# The buttons failed to work after I change the layout back

Tags: java, android

I created a login layout (start from MainActivity)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private Button regiBtn;
    private Button loginBtn;
    private Button forgotBtn;
    private EditText loginEmail;
    private EditText loginPwd;
    public static FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public static FirebaseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_task:
                fragment = new TaskFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_leadingboard:
                fragment = new LeadingBoardFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
        if(fragment!=null){

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // check if user is signed in (non-null)
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        forgotBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgotBtn);
        regiBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regiBtn);
        loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        loginPwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPwd);
        regiBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        forgotBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        // check if user is logged in or not
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.regiBtn:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.loginBtn:{
                // perform login authentication function
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail.getText().toString(), loginPwd.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    updateUI(currentUser);
                                } else{
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                break;
            }
            case R.id.forgotBtn:{
                // perform find lost password function
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ForgotPwdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateUI(FirebaseUser user){
        if(user!=null){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
            BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

            // set default to home fragment
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment())
                    .commit();
            navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see when user has logged in, the MainActivity change its layout to a bottom navigation layout where the user can choose the section to perform certain action.

In one of the fragment, I want to perform the log out function

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button logoutBtn;
    private Button storeBtn;
    private Button updateBtn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        logoutBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
        storeBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.storeBtn);
        updateBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.updateProfileBtn);

        logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v){
                MainActivity.mAuth.signOut();
                getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to change the current activity (should be MainActivity right?) layout to the activity_main (where user perform login function), the layout changed indeed, but the buttons failed to work.
The layout changed as activity_main (user log in) -> activity_dashboard (with fragments) -> main_activity (when user loggout from fragment)
I wonder where was I went wrong.

Comment: display toast when button is clicked. Check whether the button is working or not.

Comment: no, it's not working...

Comment: and I added another toast while clicking the logout button to check the current activity. Toast.makeText(getContext(), getActivity().getLocalClassName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); It prints MainActivity.

Comment: When login successfully, it should open dashboard fragment right? Why not you place the `setContentView` inside dashboard fragment?

Comment: The activity_dashboard was for another activity named DashboardActivity, but I don't want to pass the intent to change the activity. I was going to use the MainActivity for showing all the pages. Inside the activity_dashboard, I've changed tools:context=".MainActivity", but it still not working..

Comment: can you post the full project to git for me to check?

Comment: the dashboard does not have an activity now, it just an xml file that contains a fragment view and bottom navigation view

Comment: sure, it's https://github.com/pmdw620/unimelb-mobile-group78.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the layout changed indeed, but the buttons failed to work.

MainActivity is extends to `AppCompatActivity`. You should use `Intent` to open MainActivity, instead of create a new `setContentView`.

```
logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v){
               MainActivity.mAuth.signOut();
               Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);
               getActivity().finish();
           }
        });
```

Comment: but if I use intent, there is another page generated, if I click the back button on the cellphone, it will return to the dashboard which is not meant to be happed

Comment: Add `getActivity().finish();` after `startActivity(i);`.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your "Profile Fragment", in 'logout function'  try using this code:

```
Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
getActivity().finish();
```